# MySQL Workbench symbol reference

Tags: mysql, database, schema, visualization, mysql-workbench

I'm looking at a database diagram generated by MySQL Workbench (actually, DBDesigner4), but I'm not familiar with it so I couldn't figure out some of the symbols it uses for relationships and fields. Does anyone know a good legend?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215666/what-do-the-mysql-workbench-column-icons-mean-in-er-diagram

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778561/what-do-the-mysql-workbench-column-icons-mean

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model#Crow.27s_Foot_Notation), MySQL Workbench uses the Crows's Foot notation. These are (incomplete) references, but together they paint the whole picture:

- [http://college.yukondude.com/2003_09_comp210/html/note-container.php?file=02^Handout^Crow~s_Foot_Entity-Relationship_Diagram_Notation.html](http://college.yukondude.com/2003_09_comp210/html/note-container.php?file=02%5EHandout%5ECrow~s_Foot_Entity-Relationship_Diagram_Notation.html)
  (covers entities a little better);
- http://www.scribd.com/doc/464379/Crows-Foot-Notation-ER-Diagrams
  (better job at explaining cardinality
  notation);
- https://web.archive.org/web/20090724165001/http://www.gc.maricopa.edu/business/sylvester/cis164/er2b.htm (covers solid and dashed lines -- identifying and non-identifying relationships--, which are missing from the first two references).

Comment: @Pacerier markdown autolink was choking on the weird chars, fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know DBDesigner4, but I'm sometimes using MySQL Workbench.

It allows you to do modelisations using UML diagrams ; so, I suppose the symbols are quite close to those generally used with UML.

Searching about UML might get you some helpful answers ; for instance, taking a look at those pages :

- [Unified Modeling Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language)
- [Entity-relationship model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model)
- [Class diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram)

Those will probably not get you all the answers you seek ; but they will most likely at least answer some of them :-)

And reading those can only be good for you, considering you are using UML ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I found the answer (Crows's Foot notation) in one of those links. If you know a better reference to that notation, please post.