# What do the mysql workbench column icons mean

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

In MySQL Workbench, when you edit a table, by each column name, there is a colored diamond. Where can I find a document that explains what each color means?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

[image][image]Key: (Part of) Primary Key
[image][image]Filled Diamond: NOT NULL
[image][image]Not filled Diamond: NULL
[image][image][image]Red colored: (Part of) Foreign key
[image][image]Blue lined Diamond: Simple attribute (no key)

Can be combined for example:
[image] is a Red colored Key so it's a Primary Key which is also a Foreign Key
[image] is a Yellow (non Red) Key so it's only a Primary Key
[image] is a blue lined filled diamond so it's a NOT NULL simple attribute
[image] is a red colored filled diamond so it's a NOT NULL Foreign Key
[image] is a blue lined not filled diamond so it's a simple attribute which can be NULL
[image] is a red colored not filled diamond so it's a Foreign Key which can be NULL

On a sidenote:
Mind you that MySQL Workbench has a buggy **Database > Reverse Engineer (Ctrl-R)** option with which you can generate a ERD diagram and that uses these icons. In my experience the v6.x is better than v8.x but both have their quirks/bugs.

Comment: If only they would update MySQL Workbench to show these meanings when you hover over the non-intuitive icons...

Comment: I found in some cases, FK as PK is not marked with red filled key icon, so be sure to check the CREATE SQL query, in all cases.

Comment: Be sure to install the icon patch... because of a bug in some situations the icons are not shown: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92141

Answer (score 4):

> To the left of the column name is an icon that indicates whether the
>   column is a member of the primary key. If the icon is a small key,
>   that column belongs to the primary key, otherwise the icon is a blue
>   diamond or a white diamond. A blue diamond indicates the column has NN
>   set. To add or remove a column from the primary key, double-click the
>   icon. You can also add a primary key by checking the PRIMARY KEY check
>   box in the Column Details section of the table editor.

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-table-editor.html
Section: 7.7.1.3.2

Comment: I have red diamonds as well which means the column is a Foreign Key. I was wondering if there was a comprehensive list of all the possible color symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Using Google, I found this.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-using-table-tool.html

Is this enough explanation? I'd be happy to help further.