# MySQL: errno: 105 can't create table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I wanted to make a database exactly as below:

[image]

So I wanted to define the primary and foreign keys for each table.
Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28859886/5644037) answer, I saw that:

- "city" table has 1 PK (ID) and 1 FK (countrycode)
- "countrylanguage" table has 2 PK (Language and countrycode) and 1 FK 
  (countrycode)
- "country" table has 1 PK (Code)

So I tried to make some magic on a "pre-heated" code:

```
CREATE TABLE `City` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(35) NOT NULL ,
  `CountryCode` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `District` varchar(20) NOT NULL ,
  `Population` int(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY(`ID`) ,
  FOREIGN KEY(`CountryCode`) REFERENCES `Country`(`Code`)
) ;

CREATE TABLE `CountryLanguage` (
  `CountryCode` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Language` varchar(30) NOT NULL ,
  `IsOfficial` varchar(30) NOT NULL ,
  `Percentage` float(4,1) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY(`Language`),
  FOREIGN KEY(`CountryCode`) REFERENCES `Country`(`Code`)
  ) ;

CREATE TABLE `Country` (
  `Code` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Name` varchar(52) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Continent` varchar(63),
  `Region` varchar(26) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `SurfaceArea` float(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `IndepYear` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Population` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LifeExpectancy` float(3,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GNP` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GNPOld` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LocalName` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `GovernmentForm` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `HeadOfState` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Capital` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Code2` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY(`Code`)
) ;
```

but my good ol' mysql command line client has the same ERROR 1005 thing twice, and says that it can't create tables 'test.city' and 'test.countrylanguage'
with the errno:150 thingy as an explanation.

So I searched a bit around here and I found some answers regarding to table elements not having the same type/parameter (f.e. INT(2) to INT(2) NOT NULL). As fas as I could see, Nothing like this happens here.

What is my coffee-drained brain missing here?

Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: this can't be tagged as mysql and sql-server.  Pick one

Comment: i was about to make an edit removing it. im sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrong create sequnce you should create firts Country because City and CountryLanguage  refer to country table

```
CREATE TABLE `Country` (
  `Code` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Name` varchar(52) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Continent` varchar(63),
  `Region` varchar(26) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `SurfaceArea` float(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `IndepYear` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Population` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LifeExpectancy` float(3,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GNP` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GNPOld` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LocalName` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `GovernmentForm` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `HeadOfState` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Capital` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Code2` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY(`Code`)
) ;

  CREATE TABLE `City` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(35) NOT NULL ,
  `CountryCode` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `District` varchar(20) NOT NULL ,
  `Population` int(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY(`ID`) ,
  FOREIGN KEY(`CountryCode`) REFERENCES `Country`(`Code`)
) ;

CREATE TABLE `CountryLanguage` (
  `CountryCode` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Language` varchar(30) NOT NULL ,
  `IsOfficial` varchar(30) NOT NULL ,
  `Percentage` float(4,1) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY(`Language`),
  FOREIGN KEY(`CountryCode`) REFERENCES `Country`(`Code`)
  ) ;
```

Comment: Sounds right as the foreign key does not yet exist in the original

Comment: I was just about to update it to this also. Damn, you guys are fast! It works like a charm creating the tables, but as i try to insert elements to it, another error comes up (ERROR 1452 (23000): cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails).

Comment: could be you are inserting the value in the worng instance sequence .. check at the logic in your code .. or post a new question with related  code .. proper data sample and expected  result

Answer (score 3):

CREATE TABLE `Country` first, then CREATE TABLE `City`, and CREATE TABLE `CountryLanguage`, since TABLE `Country` is referenced by the other two tables.