# What do the mysql workbench column icons mean in ER Diagram?

Tags: database, icons, mysql-workbench, erd

Can any one help me in explaining about the icons in the ER Diagram of Database created in MySQL Workbench.

[image: x]

- Blue Diamond (Filled);
- Blue Diamond (unfilled);
- Red Diamond, et cetera;
  Thanks!

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778561/what-do-the-mysql-workbench-column-icons-mean/28859886#28859886

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do the mysql workbench column icons mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778561/what-do-the-mysql-workbench-column-icons-mean)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've found these resources on MySQL's website:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-using-table-tool.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-table-editor.html

> If the icon is a small key, that column belongs to the primary key,
>   otherwise the icon is a blue diamond or a white diamond. A blue
>   diamond indicates the column has NN set.

In addition to the text above, a red diamond indicates a Foreign Key association.

To answer your question:

- Blue Diamond (Filled) = indicates NOT NULL
- Blue Diamond (unfilled) = indicates NULL
- Red Diamond, et cetera = indicates a foreign key {filled: NOT NULL, unfilled: NULL}

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Now I know about these icons!

Comment: Great :) feel free to accept this as the answer, it would be much appreciated. All the best.

Comment: what about a red key ? instead of yellow one ? @DamienWilson